# ¿Cuál es la funcionalidad del operador %?

Tags: python, operador

Realizando una clase sobre Python respecto a comprehension, al momento de crear listas o diccionarios, dieron el siguiente ejemplo:

```
>>> list = [i%2 for i in range(0,10)]
>>> list
```

Y retornó:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

No me ha quedado claro en este caso cuál es la funcionalidad del operador `%`.

¿Alguien podría explicarlo?

Answer (score 3):

`%` designa el módulo o resto de la división.

- Si divides 15 entre 2, te sale 7 con un resto de 1. Es decir, 15 = 7*2 + 1.
- Si divides 15 entre 3, te sale 5 con un resto de 0. Es decir, 15 = 5*3.

En Python:

```
>>> 15 / 2
7
>>> 15 % 2
1
>>> 15 / 3
5
>>> 15 % 3
0
```

En tu caso, `i%2` está dividiendo entre 2 cada elemento del rango entre 0 y 9 y viendo cuál es su resto, lo cual sería equivalente a decir:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 10): print(i%2)
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

Este concepto está presente en prácticamente todos los lenguajes de programación y, como viste, resulta muy práctico utilizado en la comprensión de listas.

Answer (score 1):

Te esta retornando los números pares con un 1 y los impares con un 0.

El operador "%" sirve para recibir el residuo de una división